# Rubocop does not run after switching to NeoMake

Tags: ruby, neovim, rubocop, neomake

Code commands:

**~/.vimrc**

```
 91 " Run NeoMake on read and write operations
 92 autocmd! BufReadPost,BufWritePost * Neomake
 93
 94 call neomake#configure#automake('w')
 95 let g:neomake_open_list = 2
 96 let g:neomake_ruby_enabled_makers = ['rubocop']
```

**test.rb**

```
def
```

[image: Error message]

```
Neomake: rubocop: unexpected output on stderr: /Users/martins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in
`require': 
incompatible library version - 
gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.1/lib/jaro_winkler/jaro_winkler_ext.bundle (LoadError)
^Ifrom /Users/martins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
^Ifrom gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.1/lib/jaro_winkler.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
^Ifrom core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
```

(P.S. Running rubocop directly on the file works without errors.
`$ rubocop /tmp/test.rb` => OK )

Comment: This is an issue caused by conflicting gem dependencies. Try upgrading to the latest version of jaro_winkler.

Comment: same problem here. Have you found a solution?

Comment: No. :( please post your answer here if you find a solution.